# How to "emulate" a 12 column grid in Java Swing using GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am trying to position Java Swing components in a 12 columns grid, similar to what is done in CSS in web development.

I have tried the following:

```
package com.example.test;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class AddressWindow extends JFrame {

    public AddressWindow() {

        JLabel addressTypeLabel = new JLabel("Type");
        JLabel addressLineLabel = new JLabel("Address");
        JLabel zipLabel = new JLabel("ZIP");
        JLabel townLabel = new JLabel("Town");
        JLabel countyLabel = new JLabel("County");
        JLabel stateLabel = new JLabel("State");
        JLabel countryLabel = new JLabel("Country");

        JComboBox addressType = new JComboBox();
        JTextField addressLine1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField addressLine2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField zip = new JTextField();
        JTextField town = new JTextField();
        JTextField county = new JTextField();
        JTextField state = new JTextField();
        JTextField country = new JTextField();

        GridBagLayout windowLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(windowLayout);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();  
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL; 
        c.weightx = 1.0;

        // First Row 
        int posy = 0; c.gridy = posy;

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(addressTypeLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        add(addressType, c);

        c.gridx = 7;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(countryLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 9;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        add(country, c);

        // Next Row
        posy++; c.gridy = posy;

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(addressLineLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 10;
        add(addressLine1, c);

        posy++; c.gridy = posy;

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 10;
        add(addressLine2, c);

        // Next Row
        posy++; c.gridy = posy;

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(zipLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        add(zip, c);

        c.gridx = 7;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(townLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 9;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        add(town, c);

        // Next Row
        posy++; c.gridy = posy;

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(countyLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        add(county, c);

        c.gridx = 7;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(stateLabel, c);

        c.gridx = 9;
        c.gridwidth = 4;
        add(state, c);

        setSize(400,200);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        AddressWindow f = new AddressWindow();

    }

}
```

While this creates a grid, component (column) widths are not respected, as it gives the same width to every component. I am clearly not understanding how `gridwidth` works.

The intended effect would be that out of an imaginary 12 columns grid labels would take 2 columns, and input type elements 4, making a 2+4+2+4=12 column grid (except for addressLine1 and addressLine2 where there is a single label and the input field takes 10 columns). ***I.E., I am trying to make input elements be twice wide than their respective labels.***

This is the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Answer (score 0):

> The intended effect would be that out of an imaginary 12 columns

You can't just make up columns.

The size of a column is determined by the "preferred size" of the components displayed in the column.

The maximum number of components you have in any row is 4, so you have a maximum of 4 columns.

So when you create your JTextFields you should be doing something like:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

This will allow the text field to determine its preferred size based on displaying 10 "W" characters.

You should have a `weightx = 0` for all the labels (or some other value than 1.0). This means the labels will not get the extra space as the frame is resized, allowing the text fields to grow.

For the address lines you should be using `gridwidth = 3` so it spans the last 3 columns.